# Blazor WebAssembly JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported

Tags: json, blazor-webassembly

I get this error because I have circular references defined in my object model. My question is, is there any way to resolve this using one of the following two options?

1. Using Newtonsoft.Json and options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
2. Using System.Text.Json and options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve;

I'm not seeing a way to switch to Newtonsoft.Json in a Blazor WebAssembly application and I tried implementing option 2 in the ConfigureServices function of Startup.cs in my Server project but I still kept getting the error.

I'm just trying to find a solution that doesn't require me redefining my object model. The JsonIgnore attribute does not appear to be an option either because I assume, and it appears, that then any fields I define it on do not exist in the Json on the client which breaks my application.

Update: I found this site which looks to me like discusses exactly what I'm referring to here and how to implement the solution but I have not got it to work yet. If anyone is successfully using Blazor WebAssembly with circular references in your object model please let me know what you're doing.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28286

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing out this error in Blazor. I found the answer in the issue you mentioned ([this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820#issuecomment-744044536)). You need to change json options also on the Client side. This works for me:

**On server**

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

**On client**

```cs
var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<T>("{Address}", new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    ReferenceHandler =  System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = null
});
```

Comment: Is your Blazor app a WebAssembly app (client side app) or a Server app?

Comment: WebAssembly app

Comment: I used the code you posted verbatim and I still get the error. I even rebooted my machine to make sure nothing was cached. Any ideas? Can you show an example of your object model as well? Thanks.

Comment: I have to say, this solution was not perfect. It throws some different error somewhere else (but the "cycle detected" error was gone.) I moved to DTO classes and problem is solved for good... I have models with m:n relation and also with present join table. Hit me on twitter or gh if you want.

Comment: Hello, this helped me with everything. But I wonder if there is a way how to make JsonSerializerOptions for all requests on client automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To the two options you mentioned there is a third option available if you use .NET 6 or above.

3. Using System.Text.Json and options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;

Beware that ignoring cycles have issues on its own (such as data corruption) but if you were depending on it when you were using Newtonsoft.Json then you will be fine as it is basically the same behavior.

If you prefer to go with `ReferenceHandler.Preserve`, please share more info on what error you are getting and I can try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is specify how much depth an object is allowed to have. Please see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-5.0) regarding how to do this with System.Text.Json. I think this may help.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this does not seem to pertain to my issue. I didn't know what MaxDepth represented by just looking at the link you provided so i googled it and found the following link that shows an array nested 3 levels deep with MaxDepth set to 2 which then generates an error.  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MaxDepth.htm

Comment: Your circular references can cause nesting in the JSON, which is why i suggested this.

Comment: But how would I use this to resolve the issue? It looks to me like the default value is 0 which is 64 levels. I definitely do not have more than 64 levels defined so unless levels get added in essentially a never ending loop because of the circular references then i would not expect this to be an issue and if what I described happens then there's nothing i could set this value to to resolve it anyway right?

Comment: I believe you essentially are adding multiple levels due to the circular references.